# How to do custom filter in android without sequential comparison?

Tags: android

Is it possible to filter listview without sequential comparison? For ex: If i am searching for m, it has to list out the elements that contains "m" anywhere in the text. But currently its comparing "m" only at the beginning. Thanks for any help.

[image: Output]

Comment: see Filterable interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let your `ListView` adapter implement the `Filterable` interface, then you'll be required to override `gtFilter` method. Inside this method, return your own `Filter` implementation where the `performFiltering` method checks if the string that needs to be filtered contains the constraint string (search term). Simple.

Read more here: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html